# How to determine if a float is divisible by 5 in C

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to coding and taking CS50. I am trying to write my own code similar to their week 1 cash problem.
using greedy algorithm, I want to determine what is the minimum number of coins needed to give a customer his change back but using Mexican coin system. Unfortunately this coin system does not have a 0.01 cent; the lowest cent value is 0.05 cents. because of this I an running into problems determining a code that will ask for reinput of the Change due if the first input has pennies in them (example. $2.91).

this is what I have so far; I tried using some tips I saw on someone else post on some random website but it is not working.

Thank you in advance!

```
int main (void)
{
    //Cash program using Mexican coins 5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,10000

    // Input change amount
    float c;
    int cents;

    do
    {
        c = get_float("Change due: $");
        cents= round(c * 100);
        scanf("%i", & cents);
    }
    while (c < 0.0);

    //Determine if cents is divisible by 5
    if (cents % 5 == 0 )
    {

        //Start coin count
        int coins = 0;

        //Calculate coin Count
        while (cents >= 10000)
        {
            cents = cents - 10000;
            coins++;
        }
        while (cents >= 1000 && cents <10000)
        {
            cents = cents - 1000;
            coins++;
        }
        while (cents >= 500 && coins < 1000)
        {
            cents = cents - 500;
            coins++;
        }
        while (cents >= 200 && cents < 500)
        {
            cents = cents - 200;
            coins++;
        }
        while (cents >= 100 && coins < 200)
        {
            cents = cents - 100;
            coins++;
        }
        while (cents >= 50 && cents < 100)
        {
            cents = cents - 50;
            coins++;
        }
        while (cents >= 20 && cents < 50)
        {
            cents = cents - 20;
            coins++;
        }
        while (cents >= 10 && cents < 20)
        {
            cents = cents - 10;
            coins++;
        }
        while (cents >= 5 & cents < 10)
        {
            cents = cents - 5;
            coins++;
        }
        //Print
        printf("Minimum coins due: %i\n", coins);
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid Mexican currency.\n");

}
```

Comment: Do not use `float` for currency. Use integers (that is any amount is an integer number of cents).

Comment: If you are given $2.91 and don't have pennies, it will be impossible to make exact change and you will need to either round up or down.

Comment: Why are you calling `scanf("%i", & cents);` after you already got the amount with `cents= round(c * 100);`?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan That's why she does the `if (cents % 5 == 0)` check.

Comment: Your `cents % 5 == 0` test is the correct way to do it. Why do you think it's a problem?

Comment: If it's supposed to ask for reinput if the amount isn't divisible by 5, the check should be in the loop that reads input, not an `if` statement after the loop.

Comment: But I wouldn't ask for reinput. Just round the input to 5 cents. That's what they do in real life as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the check into the loop that reads input.

```
    do {
        c = get_float("Change due: $");
        cents= round(c * 100);
    } while (cents < 0 || cents % 5 != 0);
```

You don't need `scanf("%i", & cents);` since you already set `cents` on the previous line.

Then you don't need `if (cents % 5 == 0)` around the rest of the code.